# How to fix confusing TypeError with Pickle

Tags: python, pickle

I am wondering how to fix this?

I get the error:

> TypeError: file must have a 'read' attribute

```py
import pickle

myvar = input("test: ")

with open("bruh.bin","rb") as f:
    myvar = pickle.dump(myvar, 'bruh.txt')
with open("bruh.bin","rb") as f:
    myvar = pickle.load(f)
print(myvar)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply a file object to `pickle.dump()` (such as `f`), not the name of a file.

Additionally, you need to open the file you're dumping to in mode `wb` if you're going to write binary to it; `rb` will open it in read mode and you'll get an `UnsupportedOperation` or `FileNotFound` error with your current code.